# Does this differential equation have a solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was messing around with a program I wrote to trace through slope fields using Euler's method, and I noticed this equation looked particularly funny:
$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{y-x}{y\cdot\sin(y)}
$$
Is there any solution, implicit or explicit?

Comment: With a nonlinear DE like this, doubtful. I'd be surprised if it has an elementary solution...

Comment: DSolve in _Mathematica_ does not give an explicit solution.

Comment: Whether there is a solution is not necessarily the same question as whether one can write some expression for the solution.  If it lacks a closer-form solution, you should still be able to find solutions numerically.

Comment: Or you may approximate y(x) for an explicit solution; but then you must have the BV's of the interval.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y-x}{y\sin y}$

$(y-x)\dfrac{dx}{dy}=y\sin y$

Let $u=y-x$ ,

Then $x=y-u$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=1-\dfrac{du}{dy}$

$\therefore u\left(1-\dfrac{du}{dy}\right)=y\sin y$

$u-u\dfrac{du}{dy}=y\sin y$

$u\dfrac{du}{dy}-u=-y\sin y$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf